How to inhibit company mode suggestions at start of symbol?
In company mode how do I prevent the completion popup when something valid is already present? For example when refactoring C code to use a struct field instead of a local, I frequently have:
foo
and I change it to:
state->|foo
where |  is the cursor position, then it will try to popup suggestions, which I don't need. I figure if point is at the start of a symbol that should be a good signal that the completion popup is unnecessary, but I'm not sure where to hook it. I tried this, which did not work:
(defun etc-company-inhibit-at-symbol-start (orig-fun &rest args)
  (let ((bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol)))
    (unless (and bounds
                 (= (point) (car bounds)))
      (apply orig-fun args))))

(advice-add 'company-begin-backend :around #'etc-company-inhibit-at-symbol-start)

